# Exceed horizontal width in Elementor webpage

Tags: wordpress, elementor

by somehow, my webpage got exceed horizontal width.

I could not find where it came from or the cause of it.

- I did deactivatied plugin 1 by 1. Recheck custom code.

https://helion.asia/ Could friends take a look and give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HOCV.png)

You select width from your theme or plugin and override it with elementor. You give width in elemntor section. Check the section layout tab. You will find how you want to give your width boxed or full width. choose boxed and provide a custom width that you want to wish.

Comment: Oh. So this explained everything. Thanks a lot, Mijanur.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Site Width Issue]

As I can see you have given position absolute and right -value in a few images on your site.
Those images are taking up extra space on the right side.
One easy fix is to add this CSS to your stylesheet.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I think it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue with an image.
See the screenshot:https://prnt.sc/2xPZAYalQ8b6
Your image has right position in (-)
Fix the image position and do right 0.

Comment: Thank you, Jahidul. Noticed this for next counter :D